# Get the dates from a database table that are out side an array of dates

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have an array of dates for example:

```
array:5 [
  0 => "2021-12-06"
  1 => "2021-12-07"
  2 => "2021-12-08"
  3 => "2021-12-09"
  4 => "2021-12-10"
]
```

And I have a database table whose structure is like:

| id | clinic_id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

`start_date` and `end_date` are fields of datetime.

How to get all data from this table that aren't at the array, using `laravel eloquent`?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. You are searching for all tupils that have a period (start-end) outside the dates in the list?

Answer (score 0):

Are your dates strings or `Carbon` instances? You can match on a string with a LIKE query, since we're not checking the times.

If they're `Carbon` instances, first use `$str = $date->format('Y-m-d');` first.

```
$query = Clinics::query();

foreach ($dates as $date) {
    $query->where('start_date', 'not LIKE', $date.'%')
          ->where('end_date', 'not LIKE', $date.'%');
}
```